# Override save method for every class in models.Model

Tags: django, django-models

I need to get every class, that inherits models.Model to have created and updated field. I can achieve this by adding custom save method to every field,

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        self.created = timezone.now()
    self.modified = timezone.now()
    return super(`models.Model`, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

but this violates Don'tRepeatYourself rule.

I've tried to override models.Model:

```
class LogModel(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()
        self.updated = timezone.now()
        return super(LogModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and use LogModel instead of models.Model, but this failed with error E006(
The field 'x' clashes with the field 'x' from model 'y.logmodel'.

**EDIT**

My main question is how to add a custom specific field to all models in my models.py

Comment: Please make sure that your indentation is displayed correctly in the question so you don't get feedback on the wrong thing. (Especially important with Python.) Also, please elaborate on what "haven't worked" mean. What actually happened when you tried? Did it not save at all? Did it fail silently? Did it throw an exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your base model must be abstract:

```
class LogModel(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField()

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
        # Use self._state.adding to check if this is a new instance,
        # ID not being empty is not a guarantee that the instance
        # exists in the database
        # and if `update_fields` is passed, you must add the fields to the
        # list or they won't be saved in the database.
        if force_insert or self._state.adding:
            self.created = timezone.now()
            if update_fields and 'created' not in update_fields:
                update_fields.append('created')
        self.updated = timezone.now()
        if update_fields and 'updated' not in update_fields:
            update_fields.append('updated')
        return super(LogModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, if you override the `save()` method, this means it won't be editable in any form. If this is what you want, then you are better to use `auto_now` and `auto_now_add`:

```
class LogModel(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overriding **save** method, you could define **auto_now_add** and **auto_now** parameters in the Model field like:

```
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

For more information on these parameters, you can check the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField).

Comment: My main question is how to add specific field to all models.

Comment: It can be done by defining [Abstract Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) and define save method there and create all the models by inheriting from the abstract class.

Comment: Thanks. The answer was really easy.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by defining [Abstract Base Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) and define save method there and create all the models by inheriting from the abstract class. e.g.

```
class MyAbstractModel(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._state.adding:
            self.created = timezone.now()
        self.updated = timezone.now()
        return super(LogModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

and create child model class from it:

```
class Record(MyAbstractModel):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, using `update_fields` in `.save()` does not trigger fields with `auto_now`, so I overridden `save` method this way:

```py
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    _base_update_fields = ['updated_at']

    def save(
        self, force_insert=False, force_update=False,
        using=None, update_fields=None
    ):
        _update_fields = None

        if update_fields is not None:
            _update_fields = self._base_update_fields + update_fields

        super().save(
            force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update,
            using=using, update_fields=_update_fields
        )
```